# Hide parameters in UML class diagram Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml

I have written an app in Visual Studio 2013. And am generating class diagram for it, by 
first selecting Architecure -> New Diagram -> UML Class Diagram
Drag dropped classes from Architecture window to blank class diagram
Now it generated class diagrams with full parameter list to operations. And many of my methods have huge list of parameters. So it looks weird in the diagram. Whenever I double click on any operation, VS takes me to the code of that method. It feels good that what class diagram shows is exactly the signature of the method in actual code.

However I dont want parameters to be displayed in the class diagram nor I want to completely delete them. For example,

if there are 3 methods in class diagrams:

```
+meth1(param1: int) : int 
-meth2(param1 : stirng, param2 : string) : string 
#meth3(param1 : int, param2 : float) : float
```

I want some option / checkbox by which I can simply switch all those signatures to:

```
+meth1() : int 
-meth2() : string 
#meth3() : float
```

So I **dont** actually want to **manually delete** the parameter list from the method  just to hide them. By that I will keep the signature **INFORMATION** in class diagram consistent with that in code, but **just hide/show** them whenever I require it.

Somewhat, similar to SQL Server Management Studio where in diagram we can select whether to **show or hide** the data types of the column as follows:

**With datatype column**
[image]

**Without datatype column**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the menu go to CLASS DIAGRAM -> Change members format -> Display FullName